# How to close form region window on button click in VSTO outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I created a form in outlook in which I want to get user input and send this details on button click. For this purpose I am using form (form region) in outlook VSTO.

I tried Application.Quit(), but it closes outlook completely. 
I don't have option Application.Close() it doesn't come up in options

I want to close this window on button click (after sending mail) and go to explorer window (main outlook window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook object model does not provide any method to show or hide an adjoining outlook region at runtime. You may try to use the `Hide` method which the form region class provides (from the base `Control` class).

You may find similar issues:

- [Show/Hide Adjoining Form Region In Appointment](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d15f3ebc-6dcc-4a40-982c-066ed540b826/showhide-adjoining-form-region-in-appointment?forum=vsto).
- [how to show adjoining form region as expanded or collapsed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/412c542d-a04a-4446-87af-b9ee28b8a79a/how-to-show-adjoining-form-region-as-expanded-or-collapsed?forum=vsto).
- [Hiding and Showing an Adjoining Outlook Form Region](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto2/2008/01/03/hiding-and-showing-an-adjoining-outlook-form-region/).

However, you can prevent the form region from displaying at runtime, see [How to: Prevent Outlook from displaying a form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-prevent-outlook-from-displaying-a-form-region?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Also, you may consider using [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) built by Add-in Express. They provide the required methods and properties for hiding and closing form regions at runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! Your first link **(Show/Hide Adjoining Form Region In Appointment.)** work for me.